# About the Lie algebra of polyvector fields

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, dg.differential-geometry, lie-algebras, qa.quantum-algebra

I would like to know if someone already did some computations of the group of Lie algebra automorphisms of the algebra of polyvector fields on $\mathbb{R}^n$ equiped with the Schouten bracket (or another Poisson manifold).

Comment: You might want to have a look at http://people.su.se/~merku/Papers/Automorph-v4_0.pdf